# Database Search with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

Im using the folowing to search a database :

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $("#lets_search").bind('submit',function() {
          var cat1 = $('#cat1').val();
           $.post('db.php',{cat1:cat1}, function(data){
             $("#search_results").html(data);
           });
           return false;
        });
      });
    </script>
```

cat1 is the id of a drop down box. I want to add another drop down box so that the query would be :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM business
  WHERE category='".$_POST['cat1']."' and subcategory='".$_POST['cat2']."'
```

I cant seem to get the javascript to work with more than one drop down. I have tried this , but it didnt work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#lets_search").bind('submit',function() {
      var cat1 = $('#cat1').val();
       var cat2 = $('#cat2').val();
       $.post('db.php',{cat1:cat1},{cat2:cat2}, function(data){
         $("#search_results").html(data);
       });
       return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are constructing the data in wrong wya. Try with -

```
$.post('db.php',{cat1:cat1,cat2:cat2}, function(data){ ...
```

Comment: Enough in comment also.No need of answer

Comment: Thanks. Ill make this the right answer when it lets me

Comment: @SunilPachlangia know that but according to - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271229/comment-or-answer-if-the-solution-is-little. gave the answer.

Comment: Its just a question we should follow help center's guide line

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your function in more secure way by serializing the form if you have multiple elements to send.

> Blockquote
>    $.post('db.php',$('#form').serialize(), function(data){ ...});